# Is there any way using ros canopen with JointTrajectoryController by profile position mode

Tags: ros, ros-canopen, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to control my motor using canopen by JointTrajectoryController, but my motor driver do not support interpolate position mode, Please some one help me to figured out if I can use profiled position mode with PID loop? Thanks very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280724/is-there-any-way-using-ros-canopen-with-jointtrajectorycontroller-by-profile-position-mode/) by [leo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33187/leo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The profiled position mode (as implrmented in `canopen_402)` will not work properly with the `joint_trajectory_controller`. The PP mode uses one set-point which has to get acknowledged and is not meant for trajectories.

However, you can just try it for your drive. There is no need to setup a PID controlller.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0